# Find subgroup of $S_{10}$ isomorphic to $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

The only subgroup of $S_{10}$ with the same number of elements as $G$ which I can recall is $S_4$. Is this the subgroup?

Comment: Well, does $S_4$ have an element of order $6$? Is $S_4$ abelian?

Comment: You are not recalling enough. Be more creative, there are many more subgroups of order $24$ that $S_{10}$ has. Here's a hint  : an element of order $4$ and an element of order $6$ give $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_6$. Imagine these elements commuted... and $4+6=10$, so cycles...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $G=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is generated by the two commuting elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ of orders $4$ and $6$, respectively. In $S_{10}$ we can find a $4$-cycle and a $6$-cycle on disjoint sets to make them commute. Hence, consider the subgroup of $S_{10}$ generated by the cycles $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$ and $(5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10)$.

Comment: Nice, I see your point! If I call $g_1=(1\: 2\: 3\: 4\:)$ and $g_2=(5\: 6\: 7\: 8\: 9\: 10)$, is it enough to say that the map $f:S_{10}\to G$ given by $g_1^ng_2^m\mapsto (n,m)$ is a bijection?

Comment: @KasperLarsen: the map $f$ you write is not defined on all of ${\cal S}_{10}$ since there are more elements then those of the form $g_1^ng_2^m$. You may invert the direction of the arrow and then the map is injective (but not a bijection).

Comment: Ah, right. I meant the group consisting of all $g_1^ng_2^m$ for $1\leq n\leq 4,1\leq m \leq 6$ instead of $S_{10}$.